# Filter on count result and display all results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to display entries that have a count result under a certain value.
For instance, this query gives the following result on mySQL:

```
SELECT a, b, count(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY count;

+----+---+-------+  
| a  | b | count |  
+----+---+-------+  
| OK | - | 1     |  
| KO | - | 1     |  
| OK | + | 3     |  
| KO | - | 4     |  
+----+---+-------+
```

How may I display all entries that have a count result under 4 ?
i.e:

```
+----+---+-------+  
| a  | b | count |  
+----+---+-------+  
| OK | - | 1     |  
| KO | - | 1     |  
| OK | + | 3     |  
| OK | + | 3     |  
| OK | + | 3     |  
+----+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `HAVING` clause and a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t JOIN
     (SELECT a, b, count(*) as cnt
      FROM myTable
      GROUP BY a, b
      HAVING cnt < 4
     ) tt
     ON t.a = tt.a and t.b = tt.b
ORDER BY tt.cnt;
```